# Join two table using sql query

Tags: sql-server

I have two table with records, one is `temp`, second one is `temps`,
i want to update the status by department wise which is provided in the second table,

I need the first table counts will be update in the second table NotYetTaken, WorkInProgress, Completed according to the status....

For Example, 
care dept wil be update, how many completed, pending work in progress inthe Temps table replace of NULL..

### Temp Records

```
STATUS                    DEPARTMENT                 COUNT

COMPLETED                 ASSEMBLY                   1
COMPLETED                 CARE                       18
NOT YET TAKEN             CARE                       1
WORK IN PROGRESS          CARE                       1
COMPLETED                 CARE(QQ)                   6
NOT YET TAKEN             CARE(QQ)                   1
COMPLETED                 HUMAN RESOURCES            2
COMPLETED                 INFORMATION TECHNOLOGY     9
COMPLETED                 MARKETING                  1
COMPLETED                 QUALITY                    9
WORK IN PROGRESS          QUALITY                    2
COMPLETED                 RESEARCH                   1
WORK IN PROGRESS                                     1
COMPLETED                 SUB CONTRACT               3
```

### Temps Records

```
NOTYETTAKEN WORKINPROGRESS  COMPLETED   UNDERTESTING    NOTPOSSIBLE DEPARTMENT

NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    ASSEMBLY
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    CARE
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    CARE(QQ)
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    HUMAN RESOURCES
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    INFORMATION TECHNOLOGY
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    MARKETING
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    QUALITY
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    RESEARCH
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    SUB CONTRACT
```

give the sql query solution.

### EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
NOTYETTAKEN| WORKINPROGRESS |COMPLETED |UNDERTESTING |NOTPOSSIBLE   |DEPARTMENT
1   0   0   0   1   ASSEMBLY
18  7   0   4   18  CARE
6   6   6   3   6   CARE(QQ)
2   2   2   2   2   HUMAN RESOURCES
9   0   0   4   9   INFORMATION TECHNOLOGY
0   0   1   0   1   MARKETING
0   9   9   9   0   QUALITY
1   1   1   1   1   RESEARCH
1   0   0   1   1   
3   0   3   0   0   SUB CONTRACT
```

### QUERY TRIED:

```
--DROP TABLE #Temp

CREATE TABLE #Temp
(NOTYETTAKEN Int, 
WORKINPROGRESS Int, 
COMPLETED Int, 
UNDERTESTING Int,
NOTPOSSIBLE Int,
STATUSNAME Nvarchar(50),
DEPARTMENTNAME Nvarchar(50),
COUNTS Int)

INSERT INTO #Temp
SELECT 0,0,0,0,0,StatusName,DepartmentName,COUNT(*) AS 'COUNTS' 
FROM Test..Task
GROUP BY  StatusName,DepartmentName

--DROP TABLE #Temps

CREATE TABLE #Temps
(NOTYETTAKEN Int, 
WORKINPROGRESS Int, 
COMPLETED Int, 
UNDERTESTING Int,
NOTPOSSIBLE Int,
DEPARTMENTNAME Nvarchar(50),
COUNTS Int)

INSERT INTO #Temps(DEPARTMENTNAME)
SELECT DISTINCT DEPARTMENTNAME FROM Test..Task

SELECT * FROM #Temp
SELECT * FROM #Temps

UPDATE a SET 
a.NOTYETTAKEN=b.NOTYETTAKEN,
a.WORKINPROGRESS=b.WORKINPROGRESS,
a.COMPLETED=b.COMPLETED,
a.UNDERTESTING=b.UNDERTESTING,
a.NOTPOSSIBLE=b.NOTPOSSIBLE
FROM #Temps a
INNER JOIN #Temp b 
ON a.DEPARTMENTNAME=b.DEPARTMENTNAME
```

Comment: give output format of what you need

Comment: Dear, your table structure is different respect your sample of temp and temps tables

Comment: @rajeshpanchal: now i update it correctly, but i am not getting result, i need output like this.

Comment: @Joe Taras: i am using temprary table only..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table structure is not normalized.

I hope you create a table with STATUS registry like this:

```
CREATE TABLE STATUS
(id varchar(36), description varchar(50))
```

and then, you refered in your `temp` table a foreign key constraint on `status` table

But meanwhile you can try this:

```
UPDATE temps
SET NOTYETTAKEN =
    (SELECT [t.COUNT] FROM temp t WHERE T.department = temps.department
    AND t.status = 'NOT YET TAKEN'),
WORKINPROGRESS =
    (SELECT [t.COUNT] FROM temp t WHERE T.department = temps.department
    AND t.status = 'WORK IN PROGRESS'),
COMPLETED =
    (SELECT [t.COUNT] FROM temp t WHERE T.department = temps.department
    AND t.status = 'COMPLETED'),
UNDERTESTING =
    (SELECT [t.COUNT] FROM temp t WHERE T.department = temps.department
    AND t.status = 'UNDER TESTING'),
NOTPOSSIBLE =
    (SELECT [t.COUNT] FROM temp t WHERE T.department = temps.department
    AND t.status = 'NOT POSSIBLE')
```